# Best periods to observe Magellanic Clouds?

Tags: astronomy

When is the best period of the year to observe the [LMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Magellanic_Cloud) and [SMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Magellanic_Cloud) in the Southern hemisphere, so that I can observe them at a reasonable time (e.g. around 10 in the evening?). I am in Sydney.

Comment: Please specify where you reside, since it greatly depends on that. For example if you are in Northern hemisphere, say in Washington DC you can't observe LMC or SMC at all.

Answer (score 5):

The best time for the LMC is early January. The best time for the SMC is early November. These are the dates on which they are highest in the sky, but in fact both galaxies are circumpolar from Sydney and can be seen any time of year if you have a good southern horizon.

Source: Starry Night software